# Python case insensitive three level nested dictionary

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x

This is a custom case insensitive nested dictionary class created by me, its main usage is to populate QTreeWidget and keep track of said QTreeWidget, the main incentive behind this class is to prevent case insensitive duplicates from entering the tree, and to report the indexes of the nested keys (`d = {'a': {'a': {'a': {}}}}`, `fun(['a', 'a', 'a'], d) -> [0, 0, 0]`), the three level limit is deliberate, because my tree has exactly three levels.

The class:

```py
def Same(one, group):
    return next((i for i in group if i.lower() == one.lower()), None)

class TreeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def add(self, arg):
        same = Same(arg[0], self)
        if not same:
            same = arg[0]
            self.update({arg[0]: dict()})
        if len(arg) >= 2:
            rsame = Same(arg[1], self[same])
            if not rsame:
                rsame = arg[1]
                self[same].update({arg[1]: dict()})
        if len(arg) == 3:
            rrsame = Same(arg[2][0], self[same][rsame])
            if not rrsame:
                self[same][rsame].update({arg[2][0]: arg[2][1:]})
    
    def getIndex(self, arg):
        indexes = list()
        same = Same(arg[0], self)
        if same:
            i = list(self).index(same)
            indexes.append(i)
        else:
            return None
        if len(arg) >= 2:
            rsame = Same(arg[1], self[same])
            if rsame:
                j = list(self[same]).index(rsame)
                indexes.append(j)
            else:
                return None
        if len(arg) == 3:
            rrsame = Same(arg[2], self[same][rsame])
            if rrsame:
                k = list(self[same][rsame]).index(rrsame)
                indexes.append(k)
            else:
                return None
        return indexes
    
    def getValue(self, arg):
        result = self.copy()
        same = Same(arg[0], result)
        if same:
            result = result[same]
        else:
            return None
        if len(arg) >= 2:
            rsame = Same(arg[1], result)
            if rsame:
                result = result[rsame]
            else:
                return None
        if len(arg) == 3:
            rrsame = Same(arg[2], result)
            if rrsame:
                result = result[rrsame]
            else:
                return None
        return result
    
    def delete(self, arg):
        same = Same(arg[0], self)
        if not same:
            return
        if len(arg) == 1:
            self.pop(same)
        if len(arg) >=2:
            rsame = Same(arg[1], self[same])
            if not rsame:
                return
        if len(arg) == 2:
            self[same].pop(rsame)
        if len(arg) == 3:
            rrsame = Same(arg[2], self[same][rsame])
            if not rrsame:
                return
            self[same][rsame].pop(rrsame)
    
    def treefy(self, data):
        self.clear()
        for i in data:
            self.add([i.artist, i.album, [i.title, *(getattr(i, j) for j in fields[3:])]])
```

The last function is how the tree is filled, `fields` is a `list` of `str`s containing the attribute names of a `namedtuple` class, and `data` is a `list` of said `namedtuple`s.

As you can see from the code, you can also access the nested keys by inputting a list containing the keys.

I will provide some examples to demonstrate what it does:

```py
test1 = TreeDict()                                       
                                                         
from itertools import product                            
                                                         
string = 'abcdABCD'                                      
                                                         
for i, j, k in product(string, repeat=3):                
    test1.add([i, j, [k, *map(string.index, (i, j, k))]])
```

Because the output is long (64 entries) I wouldn't post it here, and everything is working correctly, if you run the loop the second time it does nothing, and as you can see there isn't a single uppercase letter.

Now I package the loop in a function:

```py
def test1():                                                
    tree = TreeDict()                                       
    for i, j, k in product(string, repeat=3):               
        tree.add([i, j, [k, *map(string.index, (i, j, k))]])
    return tree
```

Performance:

```py
%timeit test1()
2.26 ms ± 306 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Now the same structure can be achieved by this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
def test2():                                              
    tree = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))         
    for i, j, k in product(string, repeat=3):             
        tree[i][j][k] = list(map(string.index, (i, j, k)))
    return tree
```

As you can see, test2 returns 512 entries and contains all the upper case letters, and that is exactly why I wrote the case insensitive nested dictionary in the first place.

But wait, there is more:

The inferior method is tremendously faster than my superior approach:

```
%timeit test2()
477 µs ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

From multiple tests, `test2` is approximately 75% faster than `test1` if we only count execution time, and let's not forget that test2 returns 512 entries while test1 returns only 64 entries, so test2 can add 64 entries in about 3.125% the time took test1 to complete!

Now let's take the tests to insane levels:

```py
from string import ascii_letters

def test1():                                                       
    tree = TreeDict()                                              
    for i, j, k in product(ascii_letters, repeat=3):               
        tree.add([i, j, [k, *map(ascii_letters.index, (i, j, k))]])
    return tree                                                    

def test2():                                                     
    tree = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))                
    for i, j, k in product(ascii_letters, repeat=3):             
        tree[i][j][k] = list(map(ascii_letters.index, (i, j, k)))
    return tree
```

`test1` returns only 17576 entries, and `test2` returns a grand total of 140608 entries.

Performance:

```
%timeit test1()
1.24 s ± 19.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

 %timeit test2()
150 ms ± 2.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`test1` takes approximately 1.25s to complete, while `test2` takes approximately 0.15s to complete.

So test1 is approximately 1.25/0.15*140608/17576 = 66.66 times slower than test2!

How can my code be optimized?

---

I have been thinking about creating another flat dictionary subclass, in which the keys are stored in a separate dictionary as values, and their keys are the lowercases of them.

So that I can make it add new keys only if the lowercase of the key is not found in the other dict, and modify the key that equals the value of the lower case of the key in the other dict...

Sort of like this:

```
class something(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shadow = dict()
    
    def update(self, ?):
        if key.lower() not in self.shadow:
            self.shadow.update({key.lower(): key})
            self.update({key: val})
        else:
            k = self.shadow.get(key.lower())
            self.update({k: val})
```

If I can implement it correctly, this will significantly improve performance, but I don't know how to get the keys and values from the argument, and really don't know how to properly override the methods (`.get()`, `.update()`, `.pop()` etc.)...

Can anyone help me?

---

OK I will give you some more details to give you more understanding on the circumstances.

Long story short, I have been using a online music service, it allows users to post comments and the comments are terribly disgusting at best, they are completely off topic and blah blah blah, what makes me keep using it is its music recommendation functionality.

Supposedly it can recommend music for you based on your personal preferences, but in reality it misses more often than it hits, about up to a third in its daily recommendations are actually what I like, the others range from meh to disgusting, I kept using it until this year, when everything it recommends are unbearably disgusting.

But I have used it long enough to have so many songs in my playlists in my account there (about 4500), and I don't want to lose the songs, so I want to download them before I delete my account there.

And I scraped all the songs I have there and stored the entries in a MySQL database, and have found ways to programmatically download the songs...

But, the artist, album and song names are all user contributed, and the average English level of the Chinese contributors is below average at best, and inconsistency is abundant.

Same artists are credited in multiple languages, same artist's name with a typo is credited as another artist, same artist with the letters in another case? A different artist. Same artist with and without surname? Two distinct artists. Same album of the same artist with the case of one letter changed by a typo? Two albums.

To give you some more examples:

```py
In [1]: import json

In [2]: import mysql.connector

In [3]: import requests

In [4]: conn = mysql.connector.connect(
   ...:     user="Estranger", password=PWD, host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, database="Music"
   ...: )
   ...: cursor = conn.cursor()

In [5]: cursor.execute('select `artist link` from songs where artist = "Alexandrov Ensemble"')

In [6]: len(cursor.fetchall())
Out[6]: 32

In [7]: cursor.execute('select distinct `artist link` from songs where artist = "Alexandrov Ensemble"')

In [8]: ex = cursor.fetchall()

In [9]: len(ex)
Out[9]: 8

In [10]: ex
Out[10]:
[('https://music.163.com/#/artist?id=46364372',),
 ('https://music.163.com/#/artist?id=13046141',),
 ('https://music.163.com/#/artist?id=34499408',),
 ('https://music.163.com/#/artist?id=13045063',),
 ('https://music.163.com/#/artist?id=13924079',),
 ('https://music.163.com/#/artist?id=13042166',),
 ('https://music.163.com/#/artist?id=12914133',),
 ('https://music.163.com/#/artist?id=990252',)]

In [11]: for i in ex:
    ...:     print(json.loads(requests.get('http://music.163.com/api/artist/%s' % i[0].split('=')[1]).text)['artist']['name'])
俄罗斯军队模范亚历山德罗夫红旗歌舞团
Chœurs de l'armée sovietique
Orchestre Alexsandrov
The Red Army Choir
Les Choeurs De L'Armée Rouge
The Red Army Choir
Alexandrow-Ensemble - Chor Der Roten Armee
俄罗斯军乐团
```

```py
In [1]: import mysql.connector

In [2]: from collections import defaultdict

In [3]: conn = mysql.connector.connect(
   ...:     user="Estranger", password=PWD, host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, database="Music"
   ...: )
   ...: cursor = conn.cursor()

In [4]: cursor.execute('select distinct artist from songs')

In [5]: artists = cursor.fetchall()

In [6]: len(artists)
Out[6]: 1645

In [7]: dic = defaultdict(list)

In [8]:  for i in artists:
   ...:      cursor.execute('select distinct `artist link` from songs where artist = "%s"' % i[0])
   ...:      links = cursor.fetchall()
   ...:      for j in links:
   ...:          dic[i[0]].append(j)

In [9]: for i in artists:
    ...:     if len(dic[i[0]]) > 1:
    ...:         print(i[0])
Alex Blue
Alexandrov Ensemble
André Rieu
Chloë Agnew
Chöre der Arbeiterfestspiele
Céline Roscheck
Declan Galbraith
Dirk Reichardt
Grzegorz Mazur
Immediate Music
Les Choeurs Révolutionnaires
Martian
Nick Glennie—Smith
Tony Anderson
Various Artists
```

And the above are only about artists, and these are only the ones I have currently corrected (there are many more).

And there is one artist called 'SYML' with only one artist id, but credited as both 'SYML' and 'syml', and there is an album of artist 'Roberto Cacciapaglia', appeared as both 'Quarto Tempo' and 'Quarto tempo', and there are many songs with same title, album and artist because same songs got submitted by different users...

And I need the integer indexes because I need the coordinated to locate items in the tree, the tree is structured this way: artist\album\title, and items are located this way `tree.topLevelItem(0).child(0).child(0)`, so I need to get integer indices from the names.

And I need the entries unique and consistent.

And I plan to download them and store the songs this way:

`f"{BASEFOLDER}\\{artist}\\{album}\\{artist} - {title}.mp3"`

In perfect synchronization with the tree and database, and windows paths are case-insensitive, all the more reasons to make a case insensitive, duplicate not allowed, auto-correcting and ordered data class.

Comment: `treefy` won't run; `fields` is undefined.

Comment: I'm afraid that none of this makes sense to me. If `The inferior method is tremendously faster than my superior approach`, and the "inferior" method is both equivalent and expressed in a fraction of the code length, then how is your approach superior?

Comment: Why are the dictionaries nested at all? Are you just looking to have a single, triple-indexed dictionary?

Comment: And will your indexes always be one character? If not, this question is too theoretical and you need to show realistic examples.

Comment: Also very confused. Don't understand the purpose of your `getIndex` method -- why would you ever want the index of a dictionary key? Don't understand why you would want your `add` method to leave the dictionary entirely unchanged if a key entered in `add` already exists in the dictionary. I can think of some significant speed boosts here but we need some more information...

Comment: It seems like you solved your problem. Use the builtin `defaultdict` which is designed for this precise purpose (seemingly, details are unclear).

Comment: Let's discuss this in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127945/python-case-insensitive-three-level-nested-dictionary